# Is it correct to say "let's have a jumping/spinning race" to see who jumps the highest or spins the fastest?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

We say "**let's have a running race**" to see who runs the fastest.

Now, we want to see who jumps the highest or spins the fastest.

Is it correct to say "**let's have a jumping/spinning race**" or "**let's have a jumping/spinning competition**"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/race), a race is

> a competition in which all the competitors try to be the fastest and to finish first

... so I don't think it's reasonable to call it a race, if it's about who jumps highest or who spins fastest.

If there is just one single activity, you would call it a [competition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/competition). If it is one of several activities that form part of a larger competition, you would call it an [event](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/event).

Comment: then, what should we call it? "competition" how do native speakers express it in everyday English?

Comment: @Tom I have updated my answer.

Comment: _Contest_ is another possibility.

Comment: Agree, but little children may well call it a "race", and adults are not likely to have a spinning competition. Or children might say "let spin round and round and see who can spin fastest".